# Doesn't my network card support Wake-On-WLAN or why isn't it working?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I'm currently following this guide (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851581%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to enable Wake-On-WLAN, but the option "Allow this device to wake up the computer" in the device manager is greyed out. I tried to enable "Power on by PCI-E" in the BIOS (Motherboard ASUS Z97-PRO GAMER) but it didn't help. In the linked article is also stated that the function might not be available for my network card if the option is greyed out.
My network card is the TP-LINK TL-WN881ND.

Comment: "In the linked article is also stated that the function might not be available for my network card if the option is greyed out"

Answer (score 1):

It is driver dependent (Microsoft's warning box at that link says so).

You can check out How To Geek's page https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Make sure Wake on Magic Packet is enabled on the "Advanced" tab of the NIC.

HTG also points out you could check the support is there, from a linux environment.  It might be worth downloading a Live Linux CD to see if ETHTool recognizes support (again though it could be a driver difference)

TPLink's website isn't specific (manual doesn't mention it either) though the other option would be to reach out to their support directly
http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-5519_TL-WN881ND.html

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless card does not support Wake On WLAN.